# Administrator privileges on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus, administrator

I've been infected with the Conduit Search virus, and I need admin privileges to delete the files with Spybot.
However, it seems like I can't get access to them with Windows 7 Home Premium.
I use a Lenovo t430u laptop.

Also, if there is an alternative way to get rid of conduit I'd like to know.

Comment: So, if I'm getting this right, you use a regular user account, and not the administrator one. Why can't you access the admin account?

Comment: It says on the control pannel that I use the admin account but I don't have all the admin rights apparently.  When I try to delete the files using spybot it prompts me to login using the admin account, which is the only one i'm using...

Comment: You right click on spybot, and select "run as admin" from the menu and that does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Linux Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs) CD or USB drive (You can create one with [Linux Live USB creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)) to boot up the PC, and delete the offending files from that.

I recommend [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) - as I used that quite a few times to solve such issues.